# Is there a way to measure distance between points in Source engine games?

Tags: source-engine, team-fortress-2

When practicing jumps in Team Fortress 2, I'd really like to be able to measure both the height and length of my jumps, as well as the distance between two points on the map.  Is there a way in the Source engine to measure distance? Units are largely irrelevant, so long as it's consistent.

Comment: Is this on a server you control (ie. can set sv_cheats on)?

Comment: @Stuart P. Bentley It is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter `cl_showpos 1` in the [console](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Developer_Console). This will display your current position, angle, and velocity in the upper-right corner of the screen.

To get the distance, open http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-solids/distance-two-points.php in the in-game browser, plug your starting coordinates into the first box, your ending coordinates into the second box, and hit "Calculate".

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to do so exactly, unless someone made a Sourcemod to do so. What you could do is find/create a map with the default grid textures Source provides. That should provide the info you need.

Comment: I saw this awhile back, but I could never get a good estimate on distances between points at different heights - which is kind of critical since I'm figuring out jumps.  Also, being able to trace the path of a jump would be awesome.  Still - good tip, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure distances when using the Hammer editor (they are returned in something called Hammer Units; every actor / object in Source games gets a speed of Hammer Units / Second), but I don't believe there's a way to view distances in standard source games, at least not without a mod of some sort.

Comment: Hmm... If there's no horizontal speed lost when jumping, then if I could just figure out the pull of gravity in Hammer Units /Second squared, then I should be able to calculate max height and distance of jumps if I just time them with a stopwatch.  I might have to play with that a little bit.

Comment: I guess this does assume that gravity is applied through a traditional acceleration model with no terminal velocity or air resistance.  That might be an assumption I can't make.

Comment: Portal, also a source game, would seem to imply that (at least) there *is* a terminal velocity, and no air resistance, though whether those attributes are specific to Portal itself, or are adjustable, I don't know.

Comment: Excellent thought! Though it is kind of funny to me that you could have a terminal velocity without air resistance. Funny, funny, virtual reality.

Comment: This is really getting me thinking - and way off topic. I've posted a new question for this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/what-is-the-gravity-model-in-source-engine-games