# Which children can the player character kill in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

In Fallout 3, most children (*not* adolescents/teens) are made unkillable in the game. Aside from modding the game or artificially ageing them with the console, which *can* you kill anyway?

I know of two in the main game:

> You can kill Harden Simms and Maggie - they both die when you nuke Megaton.

Are there any others? What about the DLCs/expansions?

Comment: I am _this_ close to flagging this question for being abusive.

Comment: I changed the title to be, a little, more "polite".

Comment: @Drake: However, you also changed its meaning. Children killed by others, off-screen (Bumble, likely), in accidents or in the back story (I think Grayditch had some "just killed by ants" when you meet Bryan) aren't really of interest here.

Comment: Why does it matter? How is this question relevant to anything other than morbid trivia?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: It's trivia, but also something not easily found out. After all, Fallout 3 is the first in the series where the answer isn't simply "all of them".

Comment: Again, why does it matter? You can't kill children in the game. Period. Events you set into motion might result in their "death", but it's never something seen on screen.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Thus I'm not asking about "on screen". Rigging the bomb in Megaton and nuking the town is still a direct kill (with the corresponding consequences to your karma and reputation), even though *of course* you need to have a secure distance from it to survive yourself.

Comment: So a third time: *why does it matter*?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Because it's a question I have and can't easily answer (not only because it would need extensive playing, but also me having the DLCs ...), nor find the answer on the web (it might be out there somewhere, of course ... but any search I tried just leads to some mods). And it's a question about a game and its contents, this fits on Gaming.SE best, in my opinion.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Is it a problem if the question is relevant only to trivia about the results of player actions in the game?

Comment: It's a problem because we're trying to keep our site limited to asking "practical, answerable questions based on *actual problems* that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." (taken from the [FAQ]).

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: We're talking about games here. There are almost no *actual problems* to face. Pretty much every problem I see on the front page is a *gaming* one - with a possible exception for "[How can the PS3 do so much with so little RAM and VRAM?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/how-can-the-ps3-do-so-much-with-so-little-ram-and-vram)" So you're quoting here a boilerplate FAQ item which is the same on *every* SE site (even Skeptics.SE - which I find hard to believe is even *meant* for actual problems) without reflecting on how it applies to Gaming.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No children can be directly killed in Fallout 3.

I don't recall if there are children in Tenpenny Tower, but if you release the ghouls there, all the tower's inhabitants will be killed.

The evil resolution at the end of Take it Back!

> will kill all Capital Wastelanders in the long term, aside from those who were born on vaults.

You can also enslave children at the end of Those! and on Little Lamplight.

At the Brotherhood of Steel Citadel, there's Arthur Maxson, who

> will probably be killed if you choose to blow up the Citadel at the end of Who Dares Wins (in the Broken Steel add-on)

You monster.

Comment: No children are in Tenpenny Tower. The "Take it Back!" resolution is a good catch, though I don't think you see the results during the game, and at least Rivet City and Megaton have their own water purifying facilities. Does any expansion feature the smaller towns with children, like Canterbury Commons, dying off because of your decision?

Comment: No. The only expansion that builds on the decisions taken on Take it Back! is Broken Steel, and nothing is shown happening to children, specifically. EDIT: Broken Steel also shows that at least Megaton is receiving water from the Brotherhood. One would think that the problems at the water purifying plant would create a shortage.

Comment: Speaking of Broken Steel (I don't have the expansion), are there any children in either the Enclave area or the Citadel, which you can both blow up if I remember correctly?

Comment: I just remembered about [Arthur Maxson](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arthur_Maxson) , who lives in the Citadel. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Unless somebody finds other instances in other DLCs, I guess that's about it.

Comment: @MartinSojka I don't remember about other children in The Pitt, Point Lookout or Operation: Anchorage. There's Sally in Mothership Zeta, but she is unkillable.